# Installing 2 TFS 2015 and 2017 in the same DB Instance

Tags: tfs-2015

I would like to find out if more than one TFS Databases can exist in one DB instance. For example there is any existing TFS 2015 and I want to installed a new TFS 2017 and both TFS servers using the same DB instance but with different database name. Let say TFS2015_Config, TFS2017_Config etc.

Is it possible to modify the TFS configuration database with custom database name. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install TFS 2015 and 2017 in the same DB Instance.

The first thing you need to check is the [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#sql-server), make sure the SQL Server you installed is supported for both TFS 2015 and TFS 2017.

- Select **New Deployment-Advanced** option during the configuration.
- Set **Server Databases label** : (eg: **2017**)
- Also **add label or set unique name** for the first new collection.
  (By default the name is **DefaultCollection**, just make sure there
  isn't the duplicated DB name in the instance)

[image]